# Fluentd Regular Expression Matching Error

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, kubernetes, fluentd

I am trying to parse the logs from kubernetes like this for example

```
2018-08-14 13:21:20.013 [INFO][67] health.go 150: Overall health summary=&health.HealthReport{Live:true, Ready:true}
```

And this is the configuration

```
<source>
  @id calico-node.log
  @type tail
  format /^(?<time>[^ ]* [^ ,]*)[^\[]*\[[^\]]*\]\[(?<severity>[^ \]]*) *\] (?<message>.*)$/
  time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
  path /var/log/containers/calico-node**.log
  pos_file /var/log/es-calico.pos
  tag calico-node
</source>
```

According to regex101.com, this pattern should match this string. However, I get an error from fluentd while trying to parse this

````
2018-08-14 13:21:20 +0000 [warn]: [calico-node.log] "{\"log\":\"2018-08-14 13:21:20.013 [INFO][67] health.go 150: Overall health summary=\\u0026health.HealthReport{Live:true, Ready:true}\\n\",\"stream\":\"stdout\",\"time\":\"2018-08-14T13:21:20.013908223Z\"}" error="invalid time format: value = {\"log\":\"2018-08-14 13:21:20.013, error_class = ArgumentError, error = string doesn't match"```
````

What could be wrong? I have had similar errors with the built-in parser for apache logs as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, you are missing something in the `fluentd config`.

Your `time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` will not work with the timestamp `2018-08-14 13:21:20.013`, as it's missing `.%3N`.

It should be as follows:
`time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N` or `time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L`

Comment: I still get the error when I change time format to .%3N or .%L 
`2018-08-16 07:56:56 +0000 [warn]: [calico-node.log] "{\"log\":\"2018-08-16 07:56:56.103 [INFO][68] health.go 150: Overall health summary=\\u0026health.HealthReport{Live:true, Ready:true}\\n\",\"stream\":\"stdout\",\"time\":\"2018-08-16T07:56:56.104172056Z\"}" error="invalid time format: value = {\"log\":\"2018-08-16 07:56:56.103, error_class = ArgumentError, error = invalid strptime format - `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L'"`

Comment: Now the error message is different, you can try running it [here](http://fluentular.herokuapp.com/) to see any errors.

Comment: You are right. It works on Fluentular. Do you know what could be the problem? I am trying to run fluentd using the setup here https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch

Comment: What I could advice is removing all regex and starting from the beginning without groups, just the most basic regex so you can see where is the error.

Answer (score 0):

Just faced a similar issue.
I think the @Crou's answer is correct but maybe try `%N` instead.
according to the document, **fluentd** parser does not support `%3N`, `%6N`, `%9N`, and `%L`

https://docs.fluentd.org/configuration/parse-section